# jqgrid - expand all/collapse all in grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way we can implement expand all/collapse all functionality for grouping feature in jqgrid? As I understand setting groupingCollapse: true, collapses the data but I would like to make it dynamic, may be on the click of +/- icons placed within the grid. Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find the answer on your question in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369526/315935). The main idea of the answer is to use `sortnames[0]` property of the parameter `groupingView` of jqGrid. It is an array which elements can be used to constructs the ids of grouping headers and one can use `groupingToggle` method to collapse or expand the group header. In the way you can expand or collapse of all groups.

Comment: @Oleg Is there a way, I could collapse all groups in a grid when initially `groupCollapse` is `false`? I do not want the grid to collapse when it gets refreshed.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Sorry, but you wrote what you don't want, but I still don't understand your question. One can use `groupingToggle` method to expand/collapse any group from the grid. To get the names of the group(s) (the parameter of `groupingToggle`) one need use `id` from the gruop header row or one can construct it based in the information from `groupingView`, but the structure of `groupingView` depends on the version of jqGrid. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28705221/315935) for additional code fragment. What is youe question? What you need to implement?

Comment: @Oleg I want to keep the groups in the expanded state, when the grid is refreshed.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Then just remove `groupCollapse: false`. Probably you should open new question where you describe your scenario and the problem of the implementation.

Comment: @Oleg I don't want to. Is there any way we could keep the groups in the same state as before refresh?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: you speak about some scenario without to describe what you do. Which `datatype` you use? Which version of jqGrid and which fork you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? Do you need to reload **locally** or from the server? Reloading reset page number tupically to 1. Do you make some changes **before reloading** (changeing of prouping parameters and so on)? Do you need to hold the page number? You can **save** the state of opened/collapes groups, and set the same state after reloading, but the groups will be identified by group header id, which could be in some cases *another*

Comment: @Oleg I use version 4.6. I need to refresh grid at few seconds with data from the database, so I do not use `loadonce:true`. How do I save the state of  grid with opened/collapsed groups?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202378/315935), which demonstrates how to persist expand/collapse state in TreeGrid. One can use the same idea, but the implementation will be another of cause. What you ask is not a mini-question for answering in comment. You should provide the demo which demonstrates the starting point. I asked you many questions in my previous comment, but you answered only subset . You should described **detailed** the use case and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to a particular version of jqgrid, and it expands all layers, but it's so short and sweet, I just can't resist posting it.

```
function expandAll() {
    $("#myGrid .ui-icon-circlesmall-plus").trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Oleg's answer/suggestion and Jqgrid4.4.1, here is what I have done. This works when you want to expand/collapse all rows on click of some button...

```
function expandCollapseGroups(expandAll) {
    var $grid = $("#grid");
    var idPrefix =$grid[0].id + "ghead_0_", trspans;
    var groups =$grid[0].p.groupingView.groups;
    if ($grid[0].p.grouping) {
        for (var index = 0; index < groups.length; index++) {
            if (expandAll) {
                trspans = $("#" + idPrefix + index + " span.tree-wrap-" +$grid[0].p.direction + "." +$grid[0].p.groupingView.plusicon);
            } else {
                trspans = $("#" + idPrefix + index + " span.tree-wrap-" +$grid[0].p.direction + "." +$grid[0].p.groupingView.minusicon);
            }
                if (trspans.length > 0) {
                $grid.jqGrid('groupingToggle', idPrefix + index);
        }   
        }
    } 
}
```