# jqgrid > Multiple grouping collapsing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been working with a database that handles sales checks, I need to be able to first group the data by branch, then by sales person and finally by client and show all the individual checks that have been registered to each client.
I've used the groupCollapse parameter, but to my surprise it only affects the last column you add to the groupField array, so the rest of the fields, even though the collapse icon is a + sign, they appear uncollapsed.

Does anyone know of a workaround? I've tried to mess around with the groupingToggle feature but I don't really know how it works... I'm still trying to understand how javascript/jquery works so it's really hard for me to figure out a way to solve this problem.

If you need me to, I can upload my code somewhere so you can take a look at it.

**Update**

Here's the grouping part of my code:

```
grouping:true,
groupingView : {
groupField : ['Sucursal','SlpName','OCRDCardName'],
groupColumnShow : [false, false],
groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
groupCollapse : true,
groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
groupSummary : [true, true],
showSummaryOnHide: true
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xnkUr/

Comment: It doesn't sounds like you need a workaround. Something is interfering with the collapse. Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: This might help. There's another similar question linked there, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904718/jqgrid-expand-all-collapse-all-in-grouping

Comment: do share your code in a jsfiddle

Comment: @isherwood don't think there's anything wrong with the collapse, i've seen the actual code for each section of grouping and usually when there's more than one field involved there's also an option for each field on many parameters, the collapsegroup however doesn't use an array but a single boolean.

Comment: @AjoKoshy I've edited my original post with the jsfiddle

Comment: Just in case - try aligning your groupcolumnshow, grouptext, groupeorder, groupsummary arrays with 3 elements like groupfield, sometimes the strange behaviour comes from unexpected settings.

Comment: @gregory the problem is that I've tried that with two fields only and 2 elements in the arrays and it's the same result.